# Nested query in `@nestjs/graphql`, in more efficient `ResolverProperty` for all previous query result

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I'm using `@nestjs/graphql` and my code is ↓

```
@Resolver(() => Course)
export default class CourseResolver {
   @Query(() => [Course])
   course(@Args('where', { nullable: true }) where: CourseSearchDto) {
      return Course.find(where);
   }

   @ResolveProperty(() => [Profession])
   async professions(@Parent() course: Course) {
      return await Profession.find({ id: course.id });
   }
}
```

When query like this below, `profession` method is called for each `Course` but I want to run just once like a `left join` in DB.

```
{
  course {
    key,
    id,
    professions{
      id, key
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any solution to do this once and then join each `profession` for each `course` ??

Comment: "dataloader" is for that